# Emacs 23 + Erlang + Distel

Tags: emacs, erlang, emacs23

Where I can find current example of configuration and using Distel with Emacs 23 (on Mac Snow Leaoprd). I have problem with debugging (interpret mode), I cant mark brakepoint.

If anyone have working configuration of distel on emacs 23, please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one problem with using the debugger in distel is that I always need to ensure distel is loaded before setting one.

load a file, put io:format("",[]), then press M-. to navigate to io.erl, that makes sure distel is loaded

now make sure the file is intepreted, C-c, C-d, i, the minibuffer will show

now C-SPACE your line, the mark should appear

Comment: Thx for hint. This should be reported on code.google.com/p/distel ... to find out solution. Maybe some LISP/Emacs-guru can fix this.

Comment: nope this not work ... I have still "Module is not interpreted, can't set breakpoints". :(

Answer (score 1):

try this steps:

```
C-c C-d g
```

Then

```
C-c C-d i
C-c C-d m
C-x 4 0
C-c C-d m
```

Or in other order, but you should kill monitor buffer, until get not empty buffer with line like this:

```
PID          Initial Call          Status    Info
```

After try mark line for breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

I've started with the same version of Emacs. I had a similar problem.
Here's what worked for me:

1 In .emacs file I specify the name of the node with which the erlang shell is executed in Emacs

```
(setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-sname" "emacs"))
```

2 In Emacs in Erlang mode (just open an erl file):

2.1 I set the node name for Distel `C-c C-d n`

2.2 Load the Distel to the node with `C-c C-d g`

After this I am able to set the breakpoint.